# The DMARC test failed but we didn't find any obvious reason why

Tags: email, email-server, spam

One of our users recently found out his emails are going to spam for some reason. This made me dive into everything and the last thing I can't seem to figure out is the Dmarc.

We're using gmail for regular and mailgun for bulk.

Mail-tester results are as shown below:

The DMARC test failed but we didn't find any obvious reason why.
If you recently modified your DNS, please wait a few hours and then test again.

DMARC DNS entry found for the domain _dmarc.weblime.com:

```
"v=DMARC1; p= quarantine;"

Verification details:

mail-tester.com; dkim=pass (2048-bit key; unprotected) header.d=weblime.com header.i=@weblime.com header.b=AprxSQvv; dkim-atps=neutral
mail-tester.com; dmarc=none header.from=weblime.com
mail-tester.com; dkim=pass (2048-bit key; unprotected) header.d=weblime.com header.i=@weblime.com header.b=AprxSQvv; dkim-atps=neutral
From Domain: weblime.com
DKIM Domain: weblime.com
```

Comment: there's a space in your dmarc policy

```"v=DMARC1; p= quarantine;"```

Comment: Must of happened since I've been adjusting it so much. I removed the space and still no dice.

Comment: The result `dmarc=none` is not a failure, and probably not the cause of the mail being categorized as spam. After you have fixed the record and waited for TTL the DMARC test should either pass of fail, but currently it's neutral.